# Json Data is not showing in HTML page Python Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, pymongo

I am a beginner in python . I want to show json data from a python file app.py to a html template.

I tried but it showing only the names of the json .

here is my code

```
@app.route('/showUserDetail/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def showUserDetail():
try:
    userId = request.args.get('id')
    userDetail = db.userDetails.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(userId)})
    print(userDetail) # Working 
    return render_template('editUser.html',userDetails = userDetail)
```

This is My html

```
{% for x in userDetails %}
<p>{{x.name}}.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I cant find anything in the HTML page

Comment: Is data meant to be a list of people, e.g. `data= [{"name":"Deva","age":28,"Gender":"M"}]`?

Comment: actually the data is from mongodb.. .. I put a dummy data for getting a quick answer from experts

Comment: Well, what type does mongodb return, and what do you want it to be? Your template code doesn't make sense if you expect `details` to be a dictionary.

Comment: @AlexHall I will update my code

Comment: @Dfx what `print(userDetail)` shows?? Also, you use `details` variable in your HTML template, but you pass data with name `userDetails`.

Comment: its just a typing mistake in this forum , my real code is correct and not working

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for x in details %}
<p>{{x.name}}.</p>
 {% endfor %}
```

IN above code sample .The expression  you have used to refer to your data is wrong as x itself refers to dictionary key here . So referencing it as x.name won't work 
Try this

```
{% for x,y in details.items() %}
<h1>{{ x }}:{{ y }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: showing an exception "details' is undefined", while using 2nd code

Comment: you are now passing userDetails it seems !!

Comment: my real code is correct and not working.. but the print function is working properly

Comment: The thing in your template file is that you are inappropriately referencing keys in your dictionary that you pass to template file , as for each loop x corresponds to the key identifier in the dictionary i.e x is name for the first loop , age for the second round , you can't refer it as x.name as it  won't work.

Comment: sir, if i put {{x}} it showing all the  names of the variables .

Comment: yeah ! Because they are all keys in your passed dictionary like name, age.

Comment: @Dfx  If the  reponse from db is **json** , you should encode it first using json.dump and then use , see this  [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)